# Google map (api) to go from edge to edge for browser

Tags: css

I believe there is a simple solution to this problem but have not found it. I am trying to make a Google `map api` go from `edge to edge` of the browser.

I've tried putting the following into my `CSS` code. The map is now the right size, but starts not at the edge. I was thinking I can either center it or put a "left" command. But I can't figure out a way to do this.

```
html,
 body,
 #map {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;

 }
```

I tried the following and it doesn't work even though it makes sense to me

```
#map {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  left: calc((100%-100vw)/2);

 }
```

Comment: have you others div  outer  map  div? ..  all the nested  elemnt that warp the map div must  be height, width 100% for a full size map

Comment: I've tried to create a div around the map, and set it to max-width: 100%, but that does not work

Comment: Do I have to make the entire page border-to-border (and then bring the non-map elements back to normal)? That seems arduous.